# Micropython telegram bot only polls the first message in the chat history

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, esp32, micropython

I'm running a telegram bot on a esp32 with micropython using [this library](https://github.com/jordiprats/micropython-utelegram). The function it uses to poll new messages is this:

```
def read_messages(self):
    result = []
    self.query_updates = {
        'offset': self.message_offset,
        'limit': 1,
        'timeout': 30,
        'allowed_updates': ['message']}

    try:
        update_messages = urequests.post(self.url + '/getUpdates', json=self.query_updates).json() 
        if 'result' in update_messages:
            for item in update_messages['result']:
                result.append(item)
        print(len(result))
        return result
    except (ValueError):
        return None
    except (OSError):
        print("OSError: request timed out")
        return None
```

The default `self.message_offset` value is 0, but that only returns the very first message i've sent to the bot. What is the value I should use to obtain only unread messages?

EDIT: It should be mentioned that I'm using the `listen()` function, which includes code to advance the id counter

Comment: It looks like you should be calling the `read_once` method, which has code for advancing `message_offset`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention that right now I'm using the `listen` function, which includes `read_once`

Comment: Perhaps you can show us more of your code? What you've posted in your question is just the `read_messages` function from the library. What does *your* code look like?